# How to wrap meta values seperated by comma in <span>?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-value

I was able to display the single value of my custom meta field with comma separated using this code:

```
$ct = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct', true);
echo $ct;
```

And here's an output:

> USA, UK, China, Hong Kong

I needed the output to be:

```
<span>USA</span>, <span>UK</span>, <span>China</span>, <span>Hong Kong</span>
```

Is it possible? If so, a sample code would really help a lot or any reference you might know.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it's not a WordPress problem, it's a generic PHP one, look at the `explode` function. As a sidenote, you should use a taxonomy to store that information, not post meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing your meta values as a single string separated by commas, you can use the native PHP `explode()` to store them in an array:

```
$ct = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ct', true);
// Store them in an array
$country_array = explode(',' , $ct);
// Run a loop and echo them
foreach( $country_array as $key => $country ){
    echo "<span>{$country}</span>";
    echo ( ( $key < ( count( $country_array ) -1 ) ) ? ', ':'' );
}
```

This might cause issue if you have a value like this:

> Hong kong, China

Better yet save them as an array, instead of a single string.

Even better is to use custom taxonomy named `country`, and then use [`the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) to output them. This function allows you to add separator and before & after texts:

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'country', '<span>', ',', '</span> );
```

Comment: Thanks! the php explode() worked. Im storing the meta values as single string.

Comment: There's a problem tho. Why when using foreach to echo each value from array, it doubles the last value. 

For example, the input value to the meta field is:
USA, UK, China, Hong Kong

Then the outcame became: 
    <span>USA</span>, <span>UK</span>, <span>China</span>, <span>Hong Kong</span>, Hong Kong

The last value is being echoed twice.

Comment: That should not happen. Please use `print_r($country_array);` and see if the result is duplicated in that too.

Comment: Tested it with print_r($country_array); and the result isn't duplicated. Just on the foreach loop.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine for me, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtsRh.jpg). I've even added a conditional to remove the last comma.

Comment: My bad, i tripple checked my codes and noticed a typo with the value.  Maybe you could send over your conditionals for removing the last comma as well? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've already added that to my answer.